# How to use getDataFromMSDK()?

Tags: c++, dji-sdk

I have an upstream from the mobile device to the OSDK(sending a message). The data is being sent correctly but I am having issues receiving it. When looking at the OSDK API Reference, I expected the functions to use to be under the MobileCommunication class reference. The only thing I found related to upstreaming was the **getDataFromMSDK** function. I don't get how this function works, and also don't understand how receiving data on the OSDK actually works. I also don't see this function in any mobile communication samples.

How do I setup a constant listener for incoming MSDK data?
How does the **getDataFromMSDK** function come into play in this process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OSDK will call a user-defined callback whenever data is received from the MSDK.

To do this, first define a callback function that matches the typical `VehicleCallback` signature (for an example, see the [L42 in the Mobile Communication Sample from OSDK 3.6](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK/blob/3.6/sample/linux/mobile/mobile_sample.cpp#L42)). Next, call the `setFromMSDKCallback` API passing a pointer to your callback function and any data you might want to have accessible within that callback function (for an example, see [L128 in the same sample code](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK/blob/3.6/sample/linux/mobile/mobile_sample.cpp#L128)).

The final step is to access `recvFrame.recvData.raw_ack_array` in your callback function; this is the raw byte data you sent from the mobile device.

Comment: Thanks a lot, really helped! Just to confirm, I define the vehicle callback handler struct as a parameter for setFromMSDKCallback, then from this function I pass a pointer (of the handler?) to my getDataFromMSDKCallback function, and in that callback function I am able to use the data by converting raw_ack_array(which is a byte array), to whatever I want. If you couldn't tell, i'm new to this stuff. :)

Comment: wait what I said is wrong, I think I figured it out, haha.