# The use of "fromMobileSDKCallback" in DJI sdk

Tags: dji-sdk

It is stated, in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51657382/how-to-use-getdatafrommsdk?rq=1) : 
That when you want to receive data from dji-mobile sdk, you set a callback function.

Then :

> The OSDK will call a user-defined callback whenever data is received from the MSDK.

Does this mean, that if i have a code like this :

```
void fromMobileSDKCallback(
Vehicle* vehicle, RecvContainer recvFrame, UserData userData) {
 //statements with recvFrame;
 // update a global variable recvGlobal
}

vehicle->moc->setFromMSDKCallback(fromMobileSDKCallback, linuxEnvironment);
```

then, later on in a program, a block like :

```
while(true) {
// check if recvGlobal is updated
}
```

will work, and i will be able to see the changes reflected in recvGlobal indefinitely?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have too much experience with the Onboard SDK, but in theory I believe the answer is yes your approach should work.

I've done something similar in the opposite case, using mobile SDK and sendDataToOnboardSDKDevice (see my [currently unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54298058/how-to-send-data-from-usb-device-to-dji-sdk)) and through other mobile callbacks (startMission, SdCardCallbacks, etc.) where I change a global variable and it updates something elsewhere.

So, in principle the answer is yes, but I don't know enough about the onboard sdk (c++?) to know that your specific code is implemented properly.